# Implementing Nine Patch images on a Spinner - Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am working on a custom Spinner because I want the selected item in the spinner to appear inside a circle but to also have the usual triangle in the bottom right bottom of the spinner. I create the view like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/equationSpinner"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/spinner_select" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

@drawable/spinner_select is another xml file:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_spinner_disabled_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_spinner_pressed_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_spinner_focused_holo_light" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/apptheme_spinner_default_holo_light" />
</selector>
```

This xml refers to the 4 states of the Spinner and has a different 9 patch image for each state. The app runs OK but always seems to use the default image. How can I get it to use the other images when the spinner is pressed or disabled? Since the ImageView uses the spinner_select xml layout, maybe I need to somehow pass the state of the spinner to the ImageView?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was implementing the selector in the ImageView rather than in the Spinner. Switching the drawables around and reformatting worked like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|start">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/operatorSpinner"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/spinner_select"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivOperatorSpinner"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle" />
</RelativeLayout>
```